# Correct usage of Django's user_permissions and get_user_permissions()?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to understand where/how I would Django's `user_permissions` table and `get_user_permissions()` method. The only documentation I could find for it is
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_user_permissions). For example, in my app, when I assign a user `u` to a group `g`

```
>>> u.get_group_permissions()
<QuerySet [Permission...>] # the full set of permissions that the group has
>>> u.get_user_permissions()
set() # an empty set
```

First, I'd assume that `get_group_permissions()` and `get_user_permissions()` would be not only both return a QuerySet but have the same permissions. Similarly

```
>>> u.has_perm('app.view_model') # user has permission
True 
>>> u.get_user_permissions() # should permission be in here?
set()
>>> u.user_permissions.all() # what about here?
<QuerySet []>
```

Second, there also doesn't seem to be any built-in methods for adding/revoking/checking for specific user permissions other than doing operations on the `user_permissions` itself.

I guess I'm looking for clarification because I'm confused on what exactly these fields are for.